# Why is my download speed a lot lower in Linux than other OS?

Tags: networking

I had Windows 7 installed on my PC and torrents (all legal) downloaded at a rate of 2MBps. I used uTorrent.

I now have Kubuntu 13.04 installed and have kTorrent, which can only achieve speeds of 550KBps even though I know they should be downloading at the rate of 2MBps as I have tested the same downloads with windows, and it achieved those speeds.

I installed Ubuntu and Open Suse as well and all achieve the same speed of 550KBps even with different clients (rtorrent, Transmission etc), so why is this happening?

Comment: Check the arithmetic - I've seen Windows FTP clients that were off by a factor of 10 when they stated download speeds, elapsed time and bytes.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1189648 (mostly speculation, of course.)

Comment: Change your settings? KTorrent defaults to some rather conservative settings.

Comment: What about non-torrent downloads? Are they also slower?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. After reading the comment on the whirlpool forum I installed uTorrent server edition. This seems to have completely solved the problem. Thanks for all the help people!